# Application hosted on azure in .net core shows invalid dateTime.utcNow

Tags: azure, datetime, .net-core, azure-aks

I have some strange problem with API hosted in Azure K8S: When application container starts after the build it works perfectly for few days. After some time DateTime.UtcNow that I use in my code is showing date that is not correct - some times it is like 3 or 4 days stale. Did some of you have had this problem before?

1. Container DateTime in k8s pod's container is correct.
2. I don't change any localization settings in my codebase
3. I always use DateTime.UtcNow across my application.

Answer (score 0):

there is a known issue with AKS-Engine about not using the RIGHT NTP server

https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/issues/2552

this could be the source if why your timing are incorrect.

Would it be possible to use an external NTP server within your code to fetch the time outside of the current node time ?